# Building Nuget package from VS Project doesn't pick up ReadMe or Web.Config.Transform

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget

I'm attempting to build my first nuget package that requires a readme.txt to be opened and changes to be made to the web.config. I want to create a package using my csproj file as described in the 2nd page below, but I also want a web.config.transform file to be applied and readme.txt to be opened when the installation completes.

I'm attempting to follow the guidance from these two pages:

- http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CreatingANuGetPackageIn7EasyStepsPlusUsingNuGetToIntegrateASPNETMVC3IntoExistingWebFormsApplications.aspx
- https://docs.nuget.org/create/creating-and-publishing-a-package

I put the readme.txt in the root of the project directory where I'm running nuget.exe, and I created a content folder and placed the web.config.transform file in it, but neither gets applied when I install the package.

I unzipped the nupkg file and don't see anything related to readme.txt or my transform. I don't know what I'm looking for though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the tutorials that you provided in your original post, you should have a nuspec file. You should add a  section in the nuspec file which will let your package to know that files needed installed to the project too.

```
<files>
 <file src="readme.txt" target="" />
</files>
```

In addition, please check the Build Action of ReadMe file set as Content and set the Copy to Output Directory as Do not copy.

Comment: It wasn't clear exactly where to add that, but I finally figured it out. I also had an issue with local caching, so a lot of times when I tried to install I was actually trying to install the previous version. Thanks!